# Xcode 7.3 breakpoints not working when a UIWebview is displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been having problems with debugging and breakpoints for my iOS application ever since I upgraded to Xcode 7.3.

The issue comes up specifically when a UIWebview is displayed in my app. If I add a breakpoint and that piece of code is executed, Xcode basically locks up and doesn't let me stop debugging or anything. I end up having to force quit.

Has anyone else experienced this and/or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: please check the scheme, if its build and run configurations are set to debug and not release.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue with Cordova based hybrid apps on Xcode, every time I get this issue I clean the whole project and run it again everything is back to normal. Try resetting the simulator too if issue still not fixed.